# Amortized time and worst case (non-amortized) separation

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity

Assume a reasonable computation model (thinking about pointer machine or RAM model), is there a problem where there is a clear separation between amortized and worst case complexity? Say, if amortization is not allowed and only worst case for each operation is considered, the time complexity will be (provably) higher. Notice that this is different from random self-reducibility.

Comment: Heapify is one example, and there are many more...                https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/

Comment: @AviTal You're right, although this is definitely not what I've expected. Mind writing this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heapify is one example:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/

Another simpler example (Min / Max queue):
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-queue-data-structure-to-get-minimum-or-maximum-in-o1-time/  . This is also discussed here (see Szymon's answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054415/get-min-max-in-o1-time-from-a-queue

And there are many more...